# How to disable console login on linux (ideally as boot parameter)

Tags: linux, keyboard, hid, keylogger

I've got a bit of a strange use case: I have written a linux service which listens to all keyboard events and performs actions based upon them (mute incoming audio, switch a KVM input, boot a computer etc). This is the only purpose of a headless box (Raspberry Pi).

My problem is anything typed on the keyboard, as well as being registered by my service, is entered at the console login screen. Pressing "Enter" attempts to log in, which obviously fails, but causes log entries to be written about it.

Is there a way to disable console login from a linux boot parameter or similar (so I can edit it before linux starts if I need to log in locally)?

My current alternative is to setup auto login and run my code in a user session, but this feels much less secure.